# How to import routes from other file using Flask?

Tags: python, flask

[Folders in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tglR.png)

In the shared image are the folders that I have to build my app, I'm trying to do a login system but I can't access to /user/signup that I have in my routes.py

There are my files content:

**web_app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

from user import routes

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**routes.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from web_app import app #from the app module import app(web_app.py main)
from user.models import User

@app.route('/user/signup', methods=['GET'])
def signup():
    return User().signup()
```

**models.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

class User:

    def signup(self):

        user = {
            "_id": "",
            "name": "",
            "email": "",
            "password": ""
        }

        return jsonify(user), 200
```

I think I don't need nothing in **init.py** am I right?

Comment: what do you want to do with the imported routes.

Comment: No matter what I want to do and what I put on it I can't go to that route imagine route
@app.route('/asd')
def asdasd():
    return 'hey'

I can't go to localhost:5000/asd

Comment: You need to show more of your app (maybe adding your file structure would help). From what you posted you have a circular import which means you would never get this code to run. Since you are obviously getting your code to run, something is happening where `routes.py` never gets imported. And that isn't immediately apparent with what you've shown us thus far.

Answer (score 3):

You actually need to restructure you whole app. You will use flask blueprints.
first import flask blueprints in your `routes.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint
```

and take out this line:

```
from web_app import app #from the app module import app(web_app.py main)
```

then add this into your `web_app.py`:

```
from .routes import routes
    app.register_blueprint(routes)
```

And finally go back to `routes.py` and add this:

```
routes = Blueprint('routes', __name__, static_folder='static', template_folder='templates')
```

So instead of using `@app.route(...)` in your `routes.py` file you will use this:

```
@routes.route(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the bottom of your `web_app.py` file.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

How is your templates folder structured? In order for this to work the folder structure must match the URL route.

for example:

templates/

> user/
>
> > signup/
> >
> > > signup.html

Comment: Hey, I don't need to have because I'm not even trying to render a template for user/signup right now. If I put something like return "hello" that doesn't need a template it still going 404